# C# xunit unit test

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, xunit

I am writing a unit test in C# xunit for calculation. For example I have csv file with below data. What is the best practice to write unit test to calculate product price base on distinct product code.

## CSV

```
Name     Code  Price
laptop , 9999, 100.00
Mobile , 7777, 500.00
laptop , 9999, 100.00

public class Product 
{
    string Name {get;set;}
    string code {get;set;}
    string Price {get;set;}
}
```

Comment: We don't know what the calculation looks like, nor do you appear to have implemented it yet, so it's pretty hard to say much about a unit test. I'd expect a data-driven test to be useful, with various parameterised tests, but that's about all we can say now. Note that it's very unclear how this is related to ASP.NET Core at the moment, and I'd strongly advise you to store `Price` as a decimal rather than a string. (`Code` could possibly be an integer, too...)